# gcc error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory when running with non-root user

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, gcc, g++

I see that same question has been asked many times but my problem is different.

I installed gcc on ubuntu 14.04 and and it works fine with root user.
When I attempt to compile using non-root user it throws

> error gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or
>   directory

Once I compile the file with root user, non-root user is able to execute the file without any error but it is not able to compile the file.

I suspect there is a problem with file permissions and I have checked permissions for cc1 and non root user had execute permission on the file.

Comment: The error message thrown on running gcc is given in the title. I have explained that file 'cc1' exists and user has permissions to the file. Please tell me what details you need.

Comment: You might want to strace the compile and see exactly what problems the system runs into looking for `cc1`: `strace gcc -c foo.c 2>&1 | grep cc1`

Comment: How did you install gcc ? What is the command you're running that produces this error ? What does `gcc -v` reveal ? Please check which gcc binary you're actually running, in case you've somehow installed different gcc versions at different places.

Comment: Also, GCC's `-v` option might be helpful.

Comment: You may not have `build-essential`. Try installing it: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: You can ask at: askubuntu.com/ where this question would be more suitable.

Comment: gcc installation : apt-get install gcc ; 
command used to compile: gcc a.c ; 
gcc version 4.7.2 ;

This is a fresh install of gcc

Answer (score 4):

## First way:

Under the `root` account use the command:

> which gcc
>
> which cc1
>
> ls -l $Output of previous command

It will show you where are `cc1` and `gcc` and rights of `cc1`
Check that you have proper rights for `cc1` file

Then under "regular" user:

> which gcc

Output of `which gcc` should be the same as for root.

If right is ok and path to `gcc` the same as under the `root`, add `PATH` to `cc1` for user.

## Second way:

Under the `root` account:

> gcc -v hello_world.c 2>&1 | grep cc1

And do the same under the "regular" account.

It will show you the real commands that was used for compilation.

Compare them and check rights and `PATH` as in first way

---

To add PATH use: `export PATH=$PATH:$add_new_path_to_folder_here`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error was occurring while attempting to compile an updated version of ffi, nokogiri and other gems on Ubuntu. `gcc -v` revealed I was using gcc and g++ 4.8.

The fix was to switch my gcc/g++ symlinks to use 4.9 instead of 4.8.

```
$ which gcc 
$ ls -ld /usr/local/bin/gcc
$ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/gcc
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 /usr/local/bin/gcc
$ ls -ld /usr/local/bin/gcc
```

Repeat for g++.